# Calling PUBSUB commands?

Tags: redis, booksleeve

Is there any way to call the newer PUBSUB methods (http://redis.io/commands/pubsub) short of forking the BookSleeve repo?  Everywhere I look I hit a dead end.  For example, to call "PUBSUB CHANNELS", in looking at RedisConnectionBase, I could call ExecuteMultiString myself but that's set to internal.  I could do what that method does and build up a MessageResultMultiString and call EnqueueMessage, but both of those are also marked internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason this doesn't exist is that it is new in 2.8, and the latest "stable" is 2.6.16. I can add it to the roadmap, though.

For now, you could probably use `.Scripting.Eval` to issue this as LUA.

Comment: Ah, great workaround.  Thanks, Marc!  Sorry I didn't realize 2.8 was still an RC.  If it would save you some time, I was thinking about throwing it into booksleeve and submitting a pull request...?

Comment: @Tim it isn't on git - but on the plus side - it's also probably about 5 lines of code (untested)